# Kibana visualize does not show correct precision of values

Tags: kibana-5

I am using ElasticSearch and Kibana to display some temperature and humidity values.

As you can see in the Discovered screenshot, [three input data is pushed to ElasticSearch Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MehRN.png)

Three humidity values are respectively 29.42, 29.4 and 30.1. Using these three data I created a visualize as following hyperlink shown.

[Kibana Visualize Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeUbk.png)

However, this output only shows 30 and 29 values. Do you know how to modify the precision of visualization??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this may be caused by my initial data input.

My initial data input are like 25, 26, etc. Therefore, Index Pattern might learn that my values do not have decimal.

I newly created an index and input data with decimals at the very beginning then this issue does not exist anymore.

However, this still sounds strange for me because type of humidity and temperature are both number (long). It should have already taken into account decimal. Strange.